# Three.js touch intersects on mobile

Tags: mobile, three.js, touch

I'e seen this problem mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615320/touch-events-and-intersections-with-crosswalk-three-js-on-android-4-0-4-device), however this solution (e.touches[0].pageX and e.touches[0].pageY (instead of e.clientX and e.clientY) isn't working for me.

The hotspots are being selected if you touch them about 10  times, and luckily hit the magic spot, or sometimes if you hit somewhere randomly nearby they're hit, otherwise nothing.

My code:

```
        mouse.x = ( event.touches[0].pageX / window.innerWidth ) ;
        mouse.y = - ( event.touches[0].pageX / window.innerHeight );

//  This is the mouse clicks that do work        
//mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
//mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;


var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouse.x, mouse.y, 1 );

    projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

    var ray = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

    var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( targetList, true );

    if ( intersects.length > 0)
        hotspotClick(intersects[ 0 ].object);
```

EDIT

I'm making a bit of progress with this

```
        mouse.x = ( event.touches[0].pageX / window.innerWidth ) * 0.1;
        mouse.y = ( event.touches[0].pageY / window.innerHeight ) * 0.1;
```

However it seems to either be clicking anywhere near the mesh activates it, or you have to press in a certain spot somewhere in the middle of it. So I assume that multiplier is out.

X seems to be OK, Y seems to be the problem.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked

> mouse.x = +(event.targetTouches[0].pageX / window.innerWidth) * 2 +-1;
>
> mouse.y = -(event.targetTouches[0].pageY / window.innerHeight) * 2 +
>   1;

*window.innerwidth has to be window.innerWidth!*

Answer (score 2):

I have tested it on an iPad with both Chrome and Safari and on Android with Chrome.

```
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
document.addEventListener('touchend', onDocumentTouchEnd, false);

function onDocumentTouchEnd(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    mouse.x = (event.changedTouches[0].clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -(event.changedTouches[0].clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
    const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(yourObject3D);
}
```

It started to work well after appending `renderer.domElement`.

Before I was using `event.Touches` with mixed results.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to get correct intersects

event.preventDefault();

var rect = **Canvas_Instance**.getBoundingClientRect();

mouse.x = + ( (event.targetTouches[ 0 ].pageX - rect.left) / rect.width ) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = - ( (event.targetTouches[ 0 ].pageY - rect.top) / rect.height ) * 2 + 1;